# How to create a simple android test case for a utiltiy class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, junit

I've got a utility class that I've created:

```
package com.g2.quizification.utils;

import com.g2.quizification.domain.Question;

public class ParsingUtils {
    public static Question parse(String raw) {

        Question question = new Question();

        //TODO: parse some stuff

        return question;
    }
}
```

...that lives here:

[image: App with class to be tested]

I've also followed the tutorials and created a testing app, that looks like this:

[image]

And here's my test code, just waiting for some good 'ole TDD:

```
package com.g2.quizification.utils.test;


import com.g2.quizification.domain.Question;
import com.g2.quizification.utils.ParsingUtils;

public class ParsingUtilsTest  {

    public void testParse() {

        String raw = "Q:Question? A:Answer.";
        Question question = ParsingUtils.parse(raw);
        //assertEquals("Question?", question.getQuestion());
        //assertEquals("Answer.", question.getAnswer());

    }
}
```

The test class is obviously missing the extension, but all the examples seem to only show extending something like `ActivityUnitTestCase`.  *I'm not testing an activity; I just want to test a static method in a utility class.* Is that possible?

**It *seems* like creating a utility test class should be simple, but I'm not sure what the next step is and/or what I'm missing.**

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for test project is to add the test project so that its root directory tests/ is at the same level as the src/ directory of the main application's project. If you are using junit4 and eclipse, you can just right-click on the util class you want to test and choose New -> JUnit Test Case.

Basically I would expect a new test class named ParsingUtilTest under the source folder tests/ and within the package com.g2.quizification.utils.test. The test class should extend `TestCase` and each method you want to test in that util class should have a new method in the test class with the name preceded with "test". I mean to say, suppose you have a method name in `ParsingUtils` called `parseXml`. The test method name in `ParsingUtilsTest` (which Extend 'TestCase') should be named `testParseXml`

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Is this in a separate testing project or in the main/target project itself?

Comment: No the unit test are in the same project as your main project. You will have another source folder name "tests" as you have a source folder for "src"

Answer (score 0):

> The test class is obviously missing the extension, but all the examples seem to only show extending something like ActivityUnitTestCase. I'm not testing an activity; I just want to test a static method in a utility class. Is that possible?

Yes, as long as the class your are testing has nothing to do with android apis. And if you do need to test code with android api dependencies, for example, testing a view or an activity, you might want to have a try with [robolectric](http://robolectric.org). It's faster than the ones that extend ActivityUnitTestCase.

I have been playing with robolectric a lot (to do TDD on android), and so far, I prefer version 1.1 or 1.2 to 2.x, more stable and run fast.

Besides the tools mentioned above, there are many practices for writing good test cases, naming conventions, code refactoring and such.

> It seems like creating a utility test class should be simple, but I'm not sure what the next step is and/or what I'm missing.

Its good to begin with small steps, xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code and Extreme Programming Explained are some good books for your reference.